# Search bar not showing

Tags: c#, .net, maui

In my page, on Windows Machine the search bar is displayed correctly, however on mobile iOS when I test it is not displayed

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:root="clr-namespace:Orbis.Mobile"
             x:Class="Orbis.Mobile.ActivitiePage"
             xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:Orbis.Mobile.ViewModels"
             Title="">

    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <root:BytesToImageConverter x:Key="ToImage" />
    </ContentPage.Resources>
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <ScrollView>
            <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <BoxView x:Name="Box" BackgroundColor="White" />
                    <!--<SearchBar 
                    HorizontalOptions="Center"
                    WidthRequest="300"/>-->
                    <SearchBar x:Name="SearchBar" Placeholder="Search activities by Location" TextChanged="OnSearchBarTextChanged" WidthRequest="300" />
                    <ListView x:Name="LocationSuggestionsListView" ItemsSource="{Binding Suggestions}">
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ViewCell>
                                    <Label Text="{Binding .}" />
                                </ViewCell>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListView>


                    <ImageButton Grid.Row="0" Source="ic_add.png" x:Name="Plus" Clicked="Plus_Clicked"
                     VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="End" HeightRequest="35" Aspect="AspectFit" />

                    <!--<Picker x:Name="Location" HorizontalOptions="Center"
                 Title="Location"
                 ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsWithLocation}" ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Location}"  />-->

                    <StackLayout Grid.Row="4" HeightRequest="600" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Margin="0">
                        <RefreshView Command="{Binding LoadItemsCommand}" IsRefreshing="{Binding IsBusy, Mode=TwoWay}">
                            <CollectionView x:Name="ItemsListView"                ItemsSource="{Binding FilteredItems}"                SelectionMode="None">
                                <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <StackLayout Padding="10" >
                                            <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                                                <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="OnItemTapped" />
                                            </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                                            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                <Image Source="{Binding Image, Converter={StaticResource ToImage}}" 
                                                   HeightRequest="50" WidthRequest="70"/>
                                                <Label Text="{Binding Text}" LineBreakMode="WordWrap" 
                                                   Style="{DynamicResource ListItetextStyle}" FontSize="16" 
                                                   TextColor="Black"/>
                                            </StackLayout>

                                        </StackLayout>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                            </CollectionView>
                        </RefreshView>
                    </StackLayout>
                </Grid>
            </StackLayout>

        </ScrollView>

    </ContentPage.Content>

</ContentPage>
```

There are two ways for this to appear: put the searchbar at the very top of the code or remove the code who is in this block ListView

I also tried setting a background color or text color but it doesn't change anything.

First change

```
 <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
     <Grid>
         <Grid.RowDefinitions>
             <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
             <RowDefinition Height="*" />
             <RowDefinition Height="*" />
         </Grid.RowDefinitions>
         <BoxView Grid.Row="0" x:Name="Box" BackgroundColor="White" />
         <!--<SearchBar 
         HorizontalOptions="Center"
         WidthRequest="300"/>-->
         <SearchBar Grid.Row="1" x:Name="SearchBar" Placeholder="Search activities by Location" TextChanged="OnSearchBarTextChanged" WidthRequest="300" />
         <ListView Grid.Row="2" x:Name="LocationSuggestionsListView" ItemsSource="{Binding Suggestions}">
             <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                 <DataTemplate>
                     <ViewCell>
                         <Label Text="{Binding .}" />
                     </ViewCell>
                 </DataTemplate>
             </ListView.ItemTemplate>
         </ListView>
```

[image: For Windows that work]

[image: For mobile error]

Comment: Your `<StackLayout>` element is redundant.

Comment: Should I modify it or change it?

Comment: Your BoxView, SearchBar and ListView don't have any values for `Grid.Row` set, which means they will all be stacked in z-direction in the first row. This means that your ListView and Image will likely cover the SearchBar. Have you tried setting an appropriate `Grid.Row` for each element? About what Dai wrote, since the StackLayout is redundant, it can safely be removed, it's not going to change your actual problem, though. Try setting values for `Grid.Row` on your elements.

Comment: I did that but I don't see any difference, I added the extract

Comment: So in your first part, did you see your listview or your imagebutton. Please post full xaml for the second part, or try to make a minimum example. One way to test is to add your elements one by one in the grid.

Comment: I changed the first one, I added the extract, it already doesn't work

Comment: @ChrisCurt I don't see any `Grid.Row` assignments in your updated code.

Comment: Sorry I just copied wrong

Comment: @ChrisCurt And the ListView? All children of a Grid should have a `Grid.Row` or `Grid.Column` value unless the Grid only serves as a container that has only a single row and column. Maybe also show a screenshot of what it looks like at the moment and explain how it should look like (maybe use a mockup).

Comment: I also added the grid for ListView, I copied it wrong again, here are the screenshots

Comment: What happens if you use a fixed height for the row that contains the SearchBar, e.g. `RowDefinition="50"`? Does it appear when you scroll?

Answer (score 1):

I can reproduce the issue that the the [SearchBar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/searchbar) is shown correctly on Windows, however, it fails to display on iOS.

According to your code snippet, you may need to add `HeightRequest="50"` property for the [SearchBar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/searchbar) like below:

```
<Grid> 
       <Grid.RowDefinitions>
              <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
              <RowDefinition Height="50" />
              <RowDefinition Height="*" />                  
       </Grid.RowDefinitions>

      <BoxView Grid.Row="0" x:Name="Box" HeightRequest="100" Color="White" />            
      <SearchBar  Grid.Row="1" x:Name="SearchBar" Placeholder="Search activities by Location" WidthRequest="300" HeightRequest="50"/>
       <ListView  Grid.Row="2"  x:Name="LocationSuggestionsListView" ItemsSource="{Binding Suggestions}" >
               <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                           <TextCell Text="{Binding .}"/>
                     </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
       </ListView>
</Grid>
```

**PS:**

Consider using `<TextCell Text="{Binding .}"/>` for the `DataTemplate` of the ListView.

Comment: May I know whether your issue has been solved or not? If not, please share it in here. We can work together to figure it out.